# spring data lovelace m3 and spring boot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring boot 2.0.5-RELEASE, and trying to use spring data Lovelace-M3 for it's MongoDB transaction support with `MongoTransactionManager` class, i added the lovelace-m3 dependency with release train repository as follow :

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Lovelace-M3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-release</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But maven doesn't download the jar of lovealace, only the pom, can't find anywhere lovelace classes. I don't know what i am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot 2.0 does not support Spring data lovelace, if someone want to enjoy MongoDB 4 Transaction feature he needs to wait for Spring boot 2.1 unfortunately.

See : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14644

Answer (score 1):

Milestone version does not publish on https://repo.spring.io/libs-release.
Please add the following code into your  ...

```
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Also, if you need to use milestones plugin, you can add the following code:

```
 <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: that is correct, but this doesn't solve my issue, i just add the depdendency of mongodb release : 

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

i got now the mongodb 2.1 jar, i could use TransactionManagerClass, but it seems i need other classes.

Comment: Could you provide more info about "need other classes"?